# Why cant I use my newly downloaded python library?

Tags: python, import, importerror

So ive tried to install customtkinter and the installation was successfull

```
  Using cached customtkinter-4.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (246 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: darkdetect in c:\users\omen1\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from customtkinter) (0.7.1)
Installing collected packages: customtkinter
Successfully installed customtkinter-4.6.3
```

But when i then go to vs code and write import customtkinter and run it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\OMEN1\OneDrive\Skrivbord\python projects\database.py", line 290, in <module>
    import customtkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'customtkinter'
```

I have tried to uninstall and re-install
My pip is also fully uppdated aswell as my python 3.11

Ive tried multiple things

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the interpreter you're using in VSCode is aligned to where you installed the library.

For example if you installed it with Python3, your VSCode may be pointed to Python2 instead.

Additionally, according to the PyPi [link](https://pypi.org/project/customtkinter/0.3/) for that library - "To use CustomTkinter, just place the /customtkinter folder from this repository next to your program, and then you can do import customtkinter."

Comment: If using something like conda or pyenv or vanilla virtualenvs, you might also need to point to any specific environment you may have created. For instance, I have `~/.virtualenvs/PROJECTNAME/bin/python` on one Linux machine, and `~\Anaconda\envs\PROJECTNAME\python.exe` on one Windows machine.